# How to setup Travis-CI to consume dependencies from oss.sonatype.org

Tags: maven, github, travis-ci

I currently have a travis-ci setup that runs a build out of a github repository.  Previously I had no need for snapshots in oss.sonatype.org but now I do.  I'm getting an error saying that the dependency can't be found meaning that travis-ci I assume does not use it as the default maven repo.  How can I tell travis to use oss.sonatype.org as well as its default repo's setup?

edit 1: Upon further investigation i found that travis is apparently setup to use central and sonatype mirrors so i'm not sure what's going on at all.

https://travis-ci.org/FINRAOS/herd/builds/298071150

Comment: Can you provide more info on your issue? Your build logs and pom.xml for example.

Comment: I added my build logs to the end of my issue.  It links you directly to them.  As for pom.xml it's specified at the public repository that build is building off of